# How to write SCSS for Element => ElementClass => Child Class

Tags: css, sass

Hi I am using a child component which is used globally in my app. So now i want to change few CSS properties for this child component only when it is specific to my requirement.  I want to apply different properties for **description** and **end** class here. How can achieve this using SCSS and is it possible we can acheive it without important tag ?

*****HTML*******

```
<my-parent class="parent"> 
//I have added myflag to identify this has to apply only in case of my scenario
 <global-child [class.myFlag]="myFlag===true">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="description">test</div>
    <div class="end">end</div>
  </div>
</global-child>
</my-parent>
```

This is how i tried to apply my css, it is picking up height but not color for description
*****SCSS******

```
    global-child.myflag{
      height: 100px !important
    &.description{
      color: blue !important
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Kenny's answer looks good, but it still didn't work for me. The reason i am thinking is below. If that is correct how can achieve this in my scenario.

"I am adding the new CSS in my-parent.scss. And global child component has its styles in global-child component.scss. I believe my new SCSS code(which is parent) is loading before globalchild. Would that be a reason it is not reflecting on the page? "

Edit 2: 
Updated few changes in HTML above and below are my child and parent css

****global child css****

```
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  &-description {
    width: 100%;
    color: BLACK;
    position: relative;
    }
  }
```

****Parent css*****

```
  .parent{
     global-child.myflag {
        height: 100px;

       .description {
          color: blue;
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
global-child.myflag {
   height: 100px;

  .description {
      color: blue;
  }
}
```

Now when to use `&`

When you have class on same element

Like if you have element like

```
<global-child class="myflag description">
```

Then you should use `&` to apply properties to `global-child` element

But in your case `.description` is child of `global-child` element.

So this will work

```
global-child {
   &.myflag {
      // css properties

      .description {
           // css properties for `.description` those are child of `global-child.myflag
      }
   }

   .description {
           // css properties for `.description` those are child of only `global-child
      }

}
```

Comment: This looks good but it still didn't work for me. I am adding the new CSS in my-parent.scss.   And global child component has its styles in global-child component.scss. I believe my new SCSS code(which is parent)  is loading before globalchild. Would that be a reason it is not reflecting on the page? If yes then how could i achieve this in my case.

Comment: First of loading of css files shouldn't cause any issue. We must write a code in such a way that whichever files loads first or second, our code must work. Now, coming to your problem,can you please update your question with your parent css and child css. And also specify which css you want to apply in this case?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Added my prarent and child css in the question. Can you please check.

Comment: I found the issue. Issue was not with the way i was applying styles. It was due to the scoped styles. Providing viewEncapsulation as None on angular component resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kenny's answer's were right for applying the CSS styles, But the issue for me was due to style scopes in angular. Providing viewEncapsulation as NONE on my angular component resolved the issue for me.

Comment: If it did solve your problem, then you should mark it as accepted answer as community will come know, the problem is solved, it will be helpful for users who will come and see this post and I will get rep points :P

Comment: Marked Accepted. My issue was not with how I was applying styles. As I said it was due to viewencapsulation configuration. So i updated that in the answer and answered my question. Really appreciate you for taking time answer all my queries.